# Custom DebuggerDisplayAttribute for byte failing with 0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am wanting to show bytes in the format 0x00 in the Visual Studio Code debugger.

I have tried the following:

```
[assembly: DebuggerDisplay("0x{m_value.ToString(\"X2\"),nq}", Target = typeof(byte))]
```

which works where the value of the byte is non-zero.

The array `new byte[] { 0xDF, 0x86, 0x41, 0xA8, 0x00 }` shows in the debugger as:

[image]

Given that `y` is `"0x00"` after:

```
byte x = 0x00; 
var y = $"0x{x:X2}";
```

I am rather confused as to what is going on?

Many thanks for any help people can provide.

## Update

It's not quite what I was aiming for, but it is good enough and not too hacky.  I've made use of `DebuggerTypeProxy` with a simple view class for both `byte` and `byte[]` which displays as:

[image]

Comment: You do realize the debugger has a built-in option to display values as hex, right? Right click -> Hexadecimal display. Frankly, I'm surprised that what you're doing here works at all, for any value. `Byte` is essentially a fake type, and `m_value` a fake member -- they work by virtue of the runtime pretending that bytes are really instances of this struct, when they're actually, well, just bytes. Not a big surprise if you run into corner cases overriding the display of primitive types, which I heartily recommend against.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear that I want this to work in Visual Studio Code as well, where as far as I'm aware there is no hexadecimal display readily available.  I'll update the question to make this clear. Thanks.

Comment: Ouch. VS Code should really be changed/extended so it supports this. That's much more important than making `DebuggerDisplay` work correctly in all cases for primitive types (which is unsustainable when assemblies from different sources are combined). That said, have you tried `0x{ToString(\"X2\")}` (that is, calling the method directly rather than bouncing through `m_value`)? I don't really expect this to improve things, but even if it's equivalent avoiding `m_value` is better.

Comment: Also, I have no idea if this syntax even works, but if what you care about really is visualizing the `byte[]` and not so much the individual bytes, try a visualizer for `byte[]` that calls `BitConverter.ToString(this)` (careful about large arrays, though, that might need some custom code).

Comment: I think I've come up with something that is achieving close enough to what I want by using `DebuggerTypeProxy`s for target types of `byte` and `byte[]`.  I'll add an update to the question.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you've solved your issue (for some value of "solved"), feel free to post it as an answer so other people can benefit from it. Questions shouldn't contain answers.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I came up with which achieves what I wanted well enough was to make use of the `DebuggerTypeProxy` attribute rather than the `DebuggerDisplay` attribute.

I used the following:

```
[assembly: DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(ByteArrayHexView), Target = typeof(byte[]))]
[assembly: DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(ByteHexView), Target = typeof(byte))]

public class ByteArrayHexView
{
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private byte[] array;

    public string Hex => String.Join(", ", array.Select(x => $"0x{x:X2}"));

    public ByteArrayHexView(byte[] array)
    {
        this.array = array;
    }
}

public class ByteHexView
{
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private byte value;

    public string Hex => $"0x{value:X2}";

    public ByteHexView(byte value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```